# Inserting 2nd PDF into original PDF changes page ordering

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have a PDF file (roughly 200 pages) and I would like to insert another PDF that is a single page. No matter if I choose Before or After (when inserting the PDF), the document inserts the page about 10 pages before the one I'm trying to insert after. If I try to move the page to where it should be; it just moves it up further in the list. I've tried to insert other PDF documents with the same behavior so I'm not sure if my original PDF is damaged. Any advice would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you add a blank page to the target one-page PDF and then insert the other PDF between it and the page you want to insert before/after?

Comment: When inserting, on the Insert Pages dialog window, are you making sure the page location `Page: x of 200` is correct?

Comment: CharlieRB - Yes. The page count is showing up correct (123 of 200) as I'd like the inserted page to be at 124

Comment: techie007- Unfortunately, the same behavior. The blank page (instead of showing up at page 124) drops to 109.

Answer (score 0):

Source file damaged. Was able to restore a copy from 7 days ago where the insert functionality worked.

Thanks for all advice